# How do I get a comand block in Minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I try to get the comand blocks but it says can't give can mojang help

Answer (score 3):

Command blocks are unavailable in Pocket Edition. They can only be obtained in the PC version of Minecraft.